# Adding fade in effect to div class

Tags: javascript, fade

I am really new at JS. I am using this script to create tooltips:

```
<span class="SimpleTip" onMouseOver="javascript:this.className='SimpleTipHover'."onMouseOut="javascript:this.className='SimpleTip'">
```

It works perfectly but I'd like to add a fade in effect when the tooltip appears.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

You want to do something like this:

```
$('.SimpleTip').on('mouseOver', function (){ 
    $('.SimpleTipHover').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in plain javascript with timer and changing opacity but easier would be to just use jQuery to hide/show tips

or you can use [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: How can I add those functions directly to the code shown above?

Answer (score 0):

This example uses CSS Transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/mZmuQ/

**JS**

```
<span class="SimpleTip" onMouseOver="javascript:this.className='SimpleTipHover';"onMouseOut="javascript:this.className='SimpleTip';">test</span>​
```

**CSS**

```
.SimpleTip {
    background-color:green;
}
.SimpleTipHover {
    background-color:red;
}
span {
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    /* Firefox 4 */
    -moz-transition-property:background;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-transition-delay:1s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transition-property:background;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay:1s;
    /* Opera */
    -o-transition-property:background;
    -o-transition-duration:1s;
    -o-transition-timing-function:linear;
    -o-transition-delay:1s;
}
```

**RESOURCES**

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp